# Angular, inline binding logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a bit of logic to switch what is binded if the node is not there, it looks like so

```
<div {{::(search.query.term || "No Term")}} >
```

This works fine, but there are some odd scenarios where the `search.query.term` is actually and empty object and it will print `"{}"` . I'm wondering if there is a way to deal with this inline so it shows no term if the node is not there and also if it's an empty object. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldnt be jamming that logic in your html in the first place. Angularjs is perfect for an MVC model. Just put that logic in your controller and bind the result to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment you already received, put that in your controller.

```
$scope.boundValue = $scope.search.query.term || 'No Term';
```

I just ran a couple o' test runs and I never ended up with an empty object printed, unless I explicitly setup the following structure;

```
$scope.search = {
  query: {
    term: {}
  }
};
```

I'm going to assume that `term` refers to a string value.